# Harp is not serving js files from public directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, harp

I am trying to compile my app on harp js. here is my directory structure.

```
.
├── 404.html
├── _harp
│   ├── 404.jade
│   ├── _data.json
│   ├── _harp.json
│   ├── _layout.jade
│   ├── index.jade
│   ├── main.less
│   └── public
│       ├── css
│       │   ├── bootstrap.css
│       │   ├── font-awesome.min.css
│       │   ├── hoverex-all.css
│       │   ├── prettyPhoto.css
│       │   └── style.css
│       └── js
│           ├── bootstrap.min.js
│           ├── custom.js
│           ├── jquery.hoverdir.js
│           ├── jquery.hoverex.min.js
│           ├── jquery.isotope.min.js
│           ├── jquery.prettyPhoto.js
│           ├── modernizr.min.js
│           └── retina-1.1.0.js
├── index.html
├── main.css
└── public
    ├── css
    │   ├── bootstrap.css
    │   ├── font-awesome.min.css
    │   ├── hoverex-all.css
    │   ├── prettyPhoto.css
    │   └── style.css
    └── js
```

now when i try to compile the app using

```
harp compile _harp ./
```

It is not compiling the js in the js directory. as you can see in the directory tree. the js directory is always blank. I have checked the permission it seems everything what I am missing?

Comment: is it possible that the js gets inlined into `index.html`?

Comment: It is possible, but there are so many js file, if i include that it will increase complexity.

Comment: what I meant is that harp may automatically inline the scripts, but I don't think that's the case... there is this PR, that should have fixed it: https://github.com/sintaxi/harp/pull/579 maybe it's not released yet.